# Deleting a row of a tableview from another viewcontroller

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS and I need to delete a row in the tabelView (which is in tableviewcontoller) from another view (detailviewcontroller) by clicking a button in the view. Can any one explain it in objective-c language.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to go through the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Additionally read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please show your effort and that you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: use custom delegates

Comment: can u explain it in much more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276474/1142743) which will help you understand Custom delegate . please use the attached sample project which deletes a row from the detail view to the list view on button click

[Sample tableview project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqpva1s73r7l59n/TableSample.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Thank You! Vinodh .I have successfully completed the task.and once again thanks for your quick reply and hints.